# bs4 soup.find() returns none on Amazon page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the price of this product on amazon but when I use the find function from bs4 I get a none object can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import requests
Url="https://www.amazon.fr/HyperX-Cloud-Sans-fil-interrupteur/dp/B08NTYB4M7/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3O51QACXTGCAX&dchild=1&keywords=hyperx+cloud+2+wireless&qid=1630444291&sprefix=hyperx+cloud+2+w%2Caps%2C203&sr=8-2"
page=requests.get(Url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.find(id="productTitle"))
```

Comment: Amazon routinely blocks web scappers. Try to print `page.text`. You  may need a proxy server to overcome this.

Comment: Do you want to scrape the price or the product title?

Comment: the price I know the id is wrong but when I put the right id I still get a none object

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a `User-Agent` HTTP header in your request, so that Amazon believes your request is coming from a browser (e.g. Firefox) rather than a script:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}

Url = "https://www.amazon.fr/HyperX-Cloud-Sans-fil-interrupteur/dp/B08NTYB4M7/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3O51QACXTGCAX&dchild=1&keywords=hyperx+cloud+2+wireless&qid=1630444291&sprefix=hyperx+cloud+2+w%2Caps%2C203&sr=8-2"
page = requests.get(Url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text(strip=True))
```

When I run this code, it prints:

```
HyperX Cloud II Sans fil - Casque de jeu pour PC, PS4, interrupteur Nintendo, batterie longue durée (jusqu'à 30 heures), son Surround 7.1, microphone amovible à réduction de bruit et contrôle du micro
```

Comment: Curious to know how I can know the `User-Agent` for a specific website?

Comment: @ezzeddin You can visit the website with normal browser (e.g. Firefox), then open Developer tools and copy the User-Agent from there.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!